# Replace variable value in javascript using sed command

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, shell, sed

I have one variable in app.js called

> process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

i tried sed command to replace the value from development to production.

```
sed -i -e "s/process.env.NODE_ENV = \'development\';/process.env.NODE_ENV = \'production\';/g" app.js
```

But it didnt work. How to change the value in app.js file.

Comment: Remove both backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

As you use double quotes, the backslashes get interpreted by your shell. You can see that with `set -x`. The interpreted command which is called looks like:

```
sed -i -e 's/process.env.NODE_ENV = \'\''development\'\'';/process.env.NODE_ENV = \'\''production\'\'';/g' app.js
```

If you remove the backslashes, it works.